# Alt + Backquote shortcut

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts

I am looking for a way to disable system shortcut: <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Backquote</kbd> (upper tab) at my ElementaryOS Loki. It is using through IntellIJ IDEA to enable version control panel. I would like to use default IDEA shortcut because I get used to it. Do you have any idea how to disable it?

Answer (score 2):

I've found solution for enabling shortcuts in IntellIJ Idea. You have to execute this commands in terminal:

`gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings begin-move "[]"
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-group "['<Super>Above_Tab']"`